# There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.Why?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex=0;
        string str = "SELECT t1.UsrFLname from Registration t1 JOIN IMSLogin t2 on t1.RegId = t2.RegId and t2.Uname =  '" + Login1.UserName + "'";
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmdr = new SqlCommand(str, con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmdr.ExecuteReader(); 

        if (cmdr.ExecuteReader().HasRows)//here showing the error as the title i gave.
        {
            Session["userName"] = Login1.UserName.Trim();
            string myStringVariable = "Welcome! ";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myAlert", "alert('" + myStringVariable + Login1.UserName + "');", true);
            //dr.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            string myStringVariable = " No Username Found";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myAlert", "alert('" + myStringVariable + "');", true);           
        }

        con.Close();
 }
```

I used datareader object dr in the same page in other events too...
Plz help....

Comment: You might also want to separate the data access fro the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you calling ExecuteReader two times? One is enough

```
   SqlDataReader dr = cmdr.ExecuteReader(); 
   if (dr.HasRows)
   {
         -----
```

Your code has also other problems. Sql Injection is the most Dangerous. You should use code like this when passing values entered by your user

```
 string str = "SELECT t1.UsrFLname from Registration t1 JOIN IMSLogin t2 on " + 
              "t1.RegId = t2.RegId and t2.Uname = @uname";
 con.Open();
 SqlCommand cmdr = new SqlCommand(str, con);
 cmdr.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", Login1.UserName);
 SqlDataReader dr = cmdr.ExecuteReader();
```

and also using a global connection is a bad practice because you keep an expensive resource locked.  Try to use the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), open the connection, the command and the reader and then close and destroy everything

```
 // CREATE CONNECTION AND COMMAND
 using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
 using(SqlCommand cmdr = new SqlCommand(str, con))
 {
      // OPEN THE CONNECTION
      con.Open();
      cmdr.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", Login1.UserName);
      using(SqlDataReader dr = cmdr.ExecuteReader())
      { 
           // USE 
           ....
      }  // CLOSE AND DESTROY
 }  // CLOSE AND DESTROY
```

Comment: steve, thank you very much...Sql Injection is the problem always  with me ....Thank you once again 4 teaching!!

Answer (score 0):

You've already opened the reader in the line above. I think you want:

```
 SqlDataReader dr = cmdr.ExecuteReader(); 

 if (dr.HasRows)//here showing the error as the title i gave.
```

But there are other issues - SQL Injection as @Brad M points out (do a search on parameterised queries), and you're leaking your command objects - they ought to be enclosed in [`using` statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

I'm also slightly nervous about what/where `con` is defined - it smells strongly like a global variable of some kind. The general pattern for using ADO.Net is to, inside a single method/block of code, you should create a new `SqlConnection` object (inside a `using` statement), create a new `SqlCommand` object (inside a `using` statement), open the connection, execute the command, process the results (if applicable) and then exit the `using` blocks and let everything get cleaned up. Don't try to share `SqlConnection` objects around.

Answer (score 0):

you already execute reader on

```
SqlDataReader dr = cmdr.ExecuteReader();
```

So in `if`, you should use existing reader

```
dr.HasRows
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialy be careful in your sql scripts

**Avoid**

```
 string str = "SELECT t1.UsrFLname from Registration t1 JOIN IMSLogin t2 on t1.RegId =     t2.RegId and t2.Uname =  '" + Login1.UserName + "'";
```

Use

```
 string str = "SELECT t1.UsrFLname from Registration t1 JOIN IMSLogin t2 on t1.RegId =    t2.RegId and t2.Uname = @username";




con.Open();
SqlCommand cmdr = new SqlCommand(str, con);
 cmdr.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Login1.UserName);
SqlDataReader dr = cmdr.ExecuteReader(); 

if (dr.HasRows)
{

  Session["userName"] = Login1.UserName.Trim();
        string myStringVariable = "Welcome! ";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myAlert", "alert('" +   myStringVariable + Login1.UserName + "');", true);

 }
```

and DO NOT forget to

```
dr.Close();
```